# Callback url in a local script

Tags: python, api, oauth, evernote

I'm developing a local python application that can make note on evernote using evernote api.
In a web application, to implements an oauth login process, it's need to provide callback url to get_request_token method, so web application knows what to do after the request. 
But my application works as a script from command line; so what can i do in this case?

How can i work with oauth in an command line script?

```
self._client = EvernoteClient(
           consumer_key = self._settings.consumer_key,
           consumer_secret = self._settings.consumer_secret,
           sandbox=self._settings.sandbox
      )
      request_token = self._client.get_request_token(**'YOUR CALLBACK URL'**)
      print request_token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a local app, you could use [developer token](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php#devtoken) instead of doing OAuth.

Comment: thank you kentaro, now it's work. But if i wanted to publish my application, for allow to other users use it, how can i do?

Comment: Every user needs a their developer token to use this application?

Comment: If you want to publish your application and don't want users to put their developer token, you need to implement some functionality that handles callback from Evernote since OAuth in Evernote requires callback URL and out-of-band validation is not implemented yet. This forum might help: http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26357-oauth-api-vs-useridpassword/